# convert grayIplImage to color iplimage in opencv

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In opencv how do I copy and scale a greyscale image into another colour image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893464/in-opencv-how-do-i-copy-and-scale-a-greyscale-image-into-another-colour-image)

I am using this method to detect an object . The output is good but I have to convert the grayiplimage to coloriplimage (RGB) . So could any one tell me how to do this ?

```
- (void)findObject
{

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker.png"];
    objectToFind = [OpenCVUtilities CreateGRAYIplImageFromUIImage:img];

    NSLog(@"%@ %@", self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    static CvScalar colors[] = 
    {
        {{0,0,255}},
        {{0,128,255}},
        {{0,255,255}},
        {{0,255,0}},
        {{255,128,0}},
        {{255,255,0}},
        {{255,0,0}},
        {{255,0,255}},
        {{255,255,255}}
    };
    if( !objectToFind || !image )
    {
        NSLog(@"Missing object or image");
        return;
    }

    CvSize objSize = cvGetSize(objectToFind);
    IplImage* object_color = cvCreateImage(objSize, 8, 3);
    cvCvtColor( objectToFind, object_color, CV_GRAY2BGR );

    CvSeq *objectKeypoints = 0, *objectDescriptors = 0;
    CvSeq *imageKeypoints = 0, *imageDescriptors = 0;
    int i;
    CvSURFParams params = cvSURFParams(500, 1);

    double tt = (double)cvGetTickCount();
    NSLog(@"Finding object descriptors");
    cvExtractSURF( objectToFind, 0, &objectKeypoints, &objectDescriptors, storage, params );

    NSLog(@"Object Descriptors: %d", objectDescriptors->total);
    cvExtractSURF( image, 0, &imageKeypoints, &imageDescriptors, storage, params );

    NSLog(@"Image Descriptors: %d", imageDescriptors->total);
    tt = (double)cvGetTickCount() - tt;

    NSLog(@"Extraction time = %gms", tt/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.));
    CvPoint src_corners[4] = {{0,0}, {objectToFind->width,0}, {objectToFind->width, objectToFind->height}, {0, objectToFind->height}};
    CvPoint dst_corners[4];
    CvSize size = cvSize(image->width > objectToFind->width ? image->width : objectToFind->width,
                         objectToFind->height+image->height);
    output = cvCreateImage(size,  8,  1 );
    cvSetImageROI( output, cvRect( 0, 0, objectToFind->width, objectToFind->height ) );
    //cvCopy( objectToFind, output );
    cvResetImageROI( output );
    cvSetImageROI( output, cvRect( 0, objectToFind->height, output->width, output->height ) );
    //cvSetImageROI( output, cvRect( 0, 0, output->width, output->height ) );
    cvCopy( image, output );
    cvResetImageROI( output );

    NSLog(@"Locating Planar Object");
#ifdef USE_FLANN
    NSLog(@"Using approximate nearest neighbor search");
#endif
    if( locatePlanarObject( objectKeypoints, objectDescriptors, imageKeypoints,
                           imageDescriptors, src_corners, dst_corners ))
    {
        for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        {
            CvPoint r1 = dst_corners[i%4];
            CvPoint r2 = dst_corners[(i+1)%4];
            cvLine( output, cvPoint(r1.x, r1.y+objectToFind->height ),
                   cvPoint(r2.x, r2.y+objectToFind->height ), colors[6],4 );
             width = sqrt(((r1.x-r2.x)*(r1.x-r2.x))+((r1.y-r2.y)*(r1.y-r2.y)));
        }
    }
    vector<int> ptpairs;
    NSLog(@"finding Pairs");
#ifdef USE_FLANN
    flannFindPairs( objectKeypoints, objectDescriptors, imageKeypoints, imageDescriptors, ptpairs );
#else
    findPairs( objectKeypoints, objectDescriptors, imageKeypoints, imageDescriptors, ptpairs );
#endif
   /*  for( i = 0; i < (int)ptpairs.size(); i += 2 )
    {
      CvSURFPoint* r1 = (CvSURFPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( objectKeypoints, ptpairs[i] );
    CvSURFPoint* r2 = (CvSURFPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( imageKeypoints, ptpairs[i+1] );
    cvLine( output, cvPointFrom32f(r1->pt),
         cvPoint(cvRound(r2->pt.x), cvRound(r2->pt.y+objectToFind->height)), colors[8] );
    }*/

    //Distance Calculation
    float dist = 629.0/width;
    int dist1 = 629/width;
    float dist2 = dist-floor(dist);
    [distanceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance from the logo:  %d Feet %d Inches",dist1,(int)(dist2*12)]];
    //End Distance Calculation

    NSLog(@"Converting Output");
    UIImage *convertedOutput = [OpenCVUtilities UIImageFromGRAYIplImage:output];

    NSLog(@"Opening Stuff");
    [imageView setImage:convertedOutput];
    cvReleaseImage(&object_color);

    statuslabel.hidden = YES;
    spineer.hidden = YES;
    [spineer stopAnimating];
}
```

In the code output is the grayscale image . Have to convert it to color image .

Thanks in advance . Let me know if my question not clear .